# Firebase Swift: query for multiple values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchbar

I'm working on a project which uses Firebase as a backend. Within the app, you can search for hobbies with the `searchBar`, which should always give back the users who have this hobby in their profile. But it only works for one value at a time.

My Firebase is structured with something like this: `.indexOn: "name"`:

```
"hoobies" {
  KeyByAutoId
    "name": "Football"
    "sender": "Ij3YDwFRvyQLrrDprjfFf8mZzjr2"
}
```

Here is my code inside the `UISearchBar` `textDidChange` method:

```
let mainRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("hobbies")
mainRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryStarting(atValue: searchText).queryEnding(atValue: searchText).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

With this, I am already able to look for a single word, but I have no clue how or if its even possible to search for multiple words at a time.

Here a small example:

When I look for `football`, I want to show up all users who like football. If I add `basketball` to it, I want the results to filter for people how likes both of it.

Sounds easy, but I'm still a beginner and would appreciate your help! Thanks!